# Dropped in (initramfs) after installing Zorin OS 11

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, initramfs, zorin

I am trying to install Zorin OS on Fujitsu Lifebook AH530. The installation runs smoothly, but when system reboots, it drops into (`initramfs`) shell, with the message:

```
ALERT~ /dev/disk/by-uuid/.... does not exist.
```

From the shell I checked, but there is no `/dev/disk` neither there is `/dev/sda` (or any other such device).

I am installing it without keeping Windows, and I tried with many partition options (default, default with LVM, custom partitions) but non worked and was dropped in shell every time.

EDIT: Another thing that might be relative is that the `cat /proc/modules` returns nothing (it's empty).

EDIT2: Another thing I noticed the version I get from `uname -r` from `(initramfs)` shell is `3.19.0-39-generic`, but the actual kernel in boot directory (and /lib/modules/???/) is `4.2.0-23-generic`. Is that normal? if not how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the problem, by running update from the live CD.

Here's how did it.

1. boot into the Live CD
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get terminal
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt (replace sda1 to your installation root
   partition)
4. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
5. sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
6. sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
7. sudo chroot /mnt
8. apt update
9. apt upgrade

This caused system to get new version of the kernel, and I saw that during update initramfs was updated as well as grub.

So even though I didn't found out what actually caused the issue, but luckily the update solved the problem I was having.

Comment: thank you, you saved me from weird other errors, too. On one device I had an initramfs error, and I actually had to reinstall the kernel as well...